# Pass by reference vs Copy of reference

Tags: javascript, object, variables, arguments

I have understood the concept `pass by reference`.
However, the Concept `copy of reference` confuses me a little.

Is there any difference between these two **pass by reference** vs **copy of reference**?

```js
var user={
   name:"xxx"
}

function update(ref) {
  ref = {
     dep:"yyy"
  };
}

update(user);
```

When using the above code, why does it not re-initialize the `user` object?

When I update the existing property as follows:

```js
ref.name='modified'
```

It updates the `user` object.

Also, if I may ask, is the refactored code passing a **copy of reference**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It has nothing to do with passing variable by reference or not.**

In fact the problem is that you have put another object inside `ref` it doesn't point for the same object stored in `user` variable anymore.

```
function update(ref) {

  //In this line we are reinitializing the value of ref with another object
  ref = {
    dep: "yyy"
  };
  ref.name = 'modified';
}
```

**Demo :**

Let's see the difference in this snippet:

```js
var user = {
  name: "xxx"
}

function update(ref) {
  //Here we are updating ref/user 
  ref.before = "a value";
  
  //And in this line we are reinitializing the value of ref with another object
  ref = {
    dep: "yyy"
  };
  ref.name = 'modified';
  console.log('This is ref value: ');
  console.log(ref);
}
update(user);
console.log('This is user value: ');
console.log(user);
```

**Arguments in JS functions :**

And in what concerns how are the arguments passed to functions(by reference or by value) there's a difference between primitives and objects, you can read the [**MDN Functions Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) where it says:

> **Primitive parameters** (such as a number) **are passed to functions by value**; the value is passed to the function, but if the function changes the value of the parameter, this change is not reflected globally or in the calling function.
>
> If you pass **an object** (i.e. a non-primitive value, such as Array or a
>   user-defined object) as a parameter **and the function changes the
>   object's properties, that change is visible outside the function**.

Answer (score 0):

If a variable `ref` is a reference to some object `obj`, then the value in `ref` is the memory address of `obj`. Making a copy of `ref`, let's call it `ref2`, will just create another variable with the same memory address stored in it. So passing a reference or a copy of a reference is the same thing.

What would not be the same would be passing by *value* and passing by *reference*. The difference between these two are well documented online.

Comment: Now, I have an idea about copy of reference.But still its make me confused.I have updated my question